# How to recover deleted project from firebase console

Tags: firebase, firebase-console

I imported my project from by using Import Google Project in firebase console. Then I deleted it permanently thinking that I will again import it. But now when i click to import, that project is not coming in the list.
Kindly help me set it.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 146):

There is a period of roughly 30 days, during which deleted projects can be recovered.

1. To recover your project [click here](https://console.firebase.google.com/iam-admin/projects).
2. Go to the bottom left and click on the pending deletion link to recover your deleted project.
3. Click on the checkbox to select your project
4. Click on Restore.

Comment: But it doesn't show up on the firebase console after deletion. It's only in google cloud resources

Comment: @Jonathan002 they put the projects in that status and give you 30 days to recover the project if you want

Comment: I restore my project and also restore all cloud firestore data. Now everything is okay or I need to follow any other step? @JohnAlexanderBetts

Comment: No. You don't need to do anything else

Comment: Where should I find the Restore button?

Comment: @BerryBlue The restore button is above the list of the projects to be deleted.

Comment: Irurik Soft Labs please mark as right this question its relly help to all developer 
@JohnAlexanderBetts thanks

Comment: Note that some credentials (like OAuth2 client) may be not restored automatically. You need to restore them separately. For that go to "API & Services" > "Credentials" > "Restore deleted credentials" -> pick needed ones and restore them.

Comment: hello , i've deleted my project too and recover it like it's showing above , but now when i click on the project they say that This project has been recently deleted. It can be undeleted from the Cloud console .

Comment: how long does it take for you to recover to project? It's been 5 hours since I click on recover. I can see the project. But when I try to access it it still say that the project is deleted. But it is definitely recovered from the Google Console point

Comment: @leMinhNguyen Did you ever get that figured out?

Comment: @KodyVanRy ye mine was finally recovered after 3 Business days... I guess it just take time sometime

Comment: Can confirm, after 3 business days mine also was recovered.

Answer (score 17):

OK so if by mistake you have deleted your project form firebase then you would have got an email notification that your project is going to shutdown and in that mail they provide a link to restore the project with the given time frame so just click on the link and you would see list of the project that are pending to delete then check on the project you want to restore and thn click on restore

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, a linked Google console project and Firebase project use/are the same backend. If you delete one, it goes away from the other.

Comment: Thanks! for your reply. I also noticed the same and restored the deleted projects. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I have just face with this issue.
After try to reverse Firebase project and is not possible.
So my solution is remove **debug.keystore** -> Clean project -> Rebuild project. The result is I have new SHA1 key. Then can try setup again with Fire Base Assistant.

Comment: Went crazy over connecting app to firebase, which was giving me the 'app already added to another project' error.. although I cleared all my known accounts. Finally I was able to connect removing the debug keystore.

Comment: This question is not about Android.

Answer (score 1):

You can recover the projects with in a month which you have deleted your project form firebase console then you would have got an email notification that your project is going to shutdown and in that mail they provide a link to restore the project with the given time frame so just click on the link and you would see list of the project that are pending to delete then check on the project you want to restore and then click on restore.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the project unintentionally but when I clicked on the link  Restore

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).