# Why is my recovered project not visible in Firebase console?

Tags: android, firebase

I've removed from Firebase console my project (with SHA1 code) and I've tried to recover it in the Google Cloud Console (like here [How to recover deleted project from firebase console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37578421/how-to-recover-deleted-project-from-firebase-console)).

Now, my project is visible in Google Console but it doesn't appear in the Firebase console, and I don't know why. I've searched for a similar problem here but there isn't any similar.

Comment: You should contact Firebase support directly for issues relating to the Firebase console.  Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be targeted at Firebase support, who can check the project's status.