# How do you delete a firebase app from a previously deleted project?

Tags: firebase

I am using the spark plan for firebase, meaning that I have a limited number of apps allowed. I decided to delete the majority of them, but accidentally clicked "delete project" before I clicked "delete app". Now I have a bunch of apps counting toward my limit but no place to delete them from.

I have already tried going into different projects, general settings, and whatnot, as well as googling the problem and checking stack overflow. There doesn't seem to be an easy way to deal with the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You could [restore your Firebase project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37578421/how-to-recover-deleted-project-from-firebase-console), delete the app from it, then delete the project again.  If you have problems with this, you can also [reach out to Firebase support directly](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) for assistance.

Comment: Thank you so much! It never occurred to me to restore the project. Will accept your answer after the 6 minute wait time.

Comment: hmm, for some reason I am repeatedly getting the error message:

Unknown error

Tracking number: 1755217149031625044

Comment: Don't know what that means.  Please contact Firebase support.