# Firebase recover deleted hosting

Tags: firebase, firebase-hosting

simply put I can't restore a deleted hosting from firebase. For more information on how this is normally solved see [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37578421/how-to-recover-deleted-project-from-firebase-console).

The issue I have is that I never deleted a project and it doesn't show up in deleted resources. In-fact it says: 0 Resources Pending Deletion. However, when I go and create a new web-hosting with the same domain - it simply says its in use.

Any advice on how to recovered a web hosting?

Comment: If you are stuck getting something done in the Firebase CLI, please reach out to Firebase support for assistance.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After contacting Support here is what they said:

It is not possible to recover a deleted host - neither is it possible to use that domain name again due to security risks.