# Firebase connection failes with no reason at all

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have some project in [Android Studio 3.0 Beta 7](https://androidstudio.googleblog.com/2017/10/android-studio-30-beta-7-is-now.html) which uses [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/). Now, I've registered app in Firebase Console` and when I try to connect to Firebase from Android Studio Firebase plugin, I get following error:

> Firebase: No clients were able to be added to your Firebase project for the following reasons:

Here is screenshot:
[image: Problem screen capture]
The *reason* part of message **IS EMPTY** and I do not know what is wrong. I am doing this for the first time and I humbly ask for understanding.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37377973/876267) could be the answer.

Comment: Did you put the right package name and SHA-1 key in your Project setting in firebase console?

Answer (score 1):

@kernelPanic you should connect your application to firebase as shown in the image it seems that you haven't connected your app to firebase
as in the image on the right side there is only a green tick mark that shows that you have added the dependencies of firebase but haven't connected the app..
click on the button "CONNECT TO FIREBASE"  on right side.

Comment: The error pops up when I click that button `Connect to Firebase'.